# Take a div take-up all the remaing space b/w two other elements in its container

Tags: javascript, html

I have a container, and inside it three elements: A drop-down, a search bar, and a search button, from left to right.

I have fixed the drop-down to the extreme left of the container, and here's its CSS:

```
.dropdown {
  width: auto !important;
  float: left !important;
}
```

I have fixed the search-button to the extreme right, and here's its CSS:

```
.search-button {
  float: right !important;
  width: auto !important;
}
```

I want the search bar to take-up the space remaning in between the two elements. Also, the size of the drop-down varies, so the width of the search bar should change only from the left side and the right side (that is attached to the search button) should not move at all. How do I accomplish it? I have tried  **display: table** and **flexboxes** but nothing seems to work.

Thanks!

Comment: can you share your code on jsfiddle or here runnable code ?

Comment: Actually, I can't share any working code since I am using custom languages and stuff. Is the information provided in the question deficient? What more data can I provide you with?

Comment: share your html code only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CSS flex boxes are definitely what you want to use !

[flex - CSS on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/flex)

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. I added display: flex to the container, and flex: auto the middle element. The entire container shrinks. Further, when the size of the drop-down changes, even the search button moves.

Comment: Dude, can't thank you enough. Apply flex-boxes gave me some basic knowledge about CSS as well.

Comment: Glad I could help you!